# Upper bound on a contour integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration, upper-lower-bounds

I am expecting that this is a very simple question but I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Suppose that we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. In one dimension ($n=1$), I can bound the integral of $f$ as follows:
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx \leq |b-a| \sup_x f(x)
$$
When $n>1$, can I do something similar for the contour integral
$$
\oint_\mathcal{C} f(x) \cdot dx
$$
where $\mathcal{C}$ is a smooth curve from $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$? Intuitively, this would look like
$$
\oint_\mathcal{C} f(x) \cdot dx \leq ||b-a|| \sup_{x\in\mathcal{C}} ||f(x)||
$$
where $||\cdot||$ is some norm. If this works, can I use any norm (I guess not...)? I'm particularly interested in the case in which $f$ is a [conservative vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field). In that case, the integral over a closed curve ($a=b$) would yield 0 so that using $||b-a||$ in the inequality would make sense. Many thanks!

Comment: What does $dC$ mean?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't good notation. I just meant that we are integrating along a curve. I've rewritten the problem using the same notation as the "Line integral of a vector field" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral

Comment: A couple points: $b-a$ isn't the correct quantity you want (what if the integral starts and ends at the same place?) What you really want in that position is the arc length of the curve. Second, $f$ is not an element of a set with the least upper bound property, sup makes no sense. What you really want there is sup of $||f||$

Comment: I did mean sup of $||f||$. Sorry that was a (now fixed) typo. If $f$ is a conservative field (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) then the integral over a closed curve ($a=b$) should yield 0. In that case, it would make sense to use $b-a$, but that is indeed a special case (I have added some language to clarify this).